# textblob error 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python-3.x, translate, textblob

[image: 1]

I'm using TextBlob to translate some text , it worked fine till I tested it today ...
I'm using python 3
textblob Version: 0.15.3.
Is there a new update or something like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's been deprecated, and suggest using official Google Translate API:

> 0.16.0 (2020-04-26) Deprecations:
>
> TextBlob.translate() and TextBlob.detect_language are deprecated. Use
> the official Google Translate API instead (#215). Other changes:
>
> Backwards-incompatible: Drop support for Python 3.4. Test against
> Python 3.7 and Python 3.8. Pin NLTK to nltk<3.5 on Python 2 (#315).

you can find such warning in the new version of the library:
'''Translate the word to another language using Google's
Translate API.

```
    .. deprecated:: 0.16.0
        Use the official Google Translate API instead.
    .. versionadded:: 0.5.0
    '''
```

it appears that google blocks a request and asks to solve captcha:
https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/215

Answer (score 10):

I suggest that you explicitly specify the input language

```py
blob = TextBlob("hello")
blob.translate(from_lang='en', to='fr')
```

Here is the output

```py
TextBlob("bonjour")
```

Answer (score 0):

referred by
https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/371

The issue has been fixed.